# Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to insert a record in Oracle database through Java. This is my code

```
public class CheckDateTime {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{  
        Class.forName("Driver");  

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("url","uname","pwd");  
        String text = "2013-09-04 13:30:00";
        Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(text);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");  
        String strDate= formatter.format(ts);  
        String query = "INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES(?,?);";        
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setString(1, "SK");
        stmt.setTimestamp(2, ts);
        System.out.println(stmt.executeUpdate());

        con.close();  

        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  

}}
```

But this seems to throw an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
```

I do not understand the root cause of this error can someone please help me out.

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace. With code as shown, `Timestamp.valueOf` will not throw an exception with `"2013-09-04 13:30:00"`. The formatting you do is entirely unnecessary, because you don't even use the result of `strDate`.

Comment: `formatter` and `strDate` is not used at all in your code which causes confusion, remove unnecessary code.

Comment: @Frieder No, using `setTimestamp` is the right call.

Comment: Change to

 String text = "2013-09-04 13:30:00.00";